# How to build samba on one machine and install binaries on the other machine?

Tags: linux, installation, samba

I read article about building Samba from sources:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Build_Samba_from_Source

It is quite simple:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The question is: Is it possible to build samba on one machine, copy binaries to other and install samba there ?

Answer (score 0):

Most makefiles accept a `DESTDIR` argument, which redirects the installation process to separate directory tree, instead of the operating system installation itself.

So you can do this (at least at a conceptual level; but I did check that Samba supports `DESTDIR`):

```
./configure
make
mkdir tmproot
sudo make DESTDIR=`pwd`/tmproot install
```

`sudo` is still require to create the files with the right permission and ownership.

You can then put the contents of `tmproot` into a tarball, copy that to the destination system, and unpack it there.  You may have to create relevant system accounts on the target first, though.

You could also look at the Samba package building scripts for your distribution.  It does all this behind the scenes: installing into a temporary directory, and making sure that when the package is installed, all prerequisites such as system accounts are met.